# how to select one or more item from web page JComboBox using Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework, jcombobox

I was wondering if any of you could help me figure how to click and select one or more items from a JComboBox form?

I was trying to use the keyword Select From List, however it doesn't seem to work...

Here's an example of what I am trying to manipulate using the Robot Framework.

[combobox_element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAVxV.png)

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Can you paste the code you have written so far?

Comment: You have no code here for anyone to review, I think you can benefit from reading over this documentation: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: Note added in Answer which was previously in comment.

Note: For your information code is in the java.

To get focus to the Dropdown list, you may use click() or if you know value from dropdown list, you may use sendkeys().

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath of the element")).sendKeys("");
```

Use 'Robot class' to send values to the field, you may need to use it multiple times based on your selections.

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```